# Android. Storing and sending data while phone is offline

Tags: java, android, post, android-asynctask, storage

I've made application for Android which listens for bluetooth beacons which are placed across different rooms, and it stores data to server whether someone is in the room or not.

To send data to server I'm using AsyncTask objects so everytime I'm sending data I just make a new AsyncTask object and call its doInBackground() where I do the sending (I'm sure there is a lot better solution).

My problems so far:

1. When there is no internet connection, I'm storing data into ArrayList so I could resend it once the internet connection is back up.
   This approach will use a lot of RAM so I just wanna know what's the best way to do this and how should I store the data?
2. For some reason AsyncTask is not sending data when it should (I'm basically doing simple POST request to the server). So in some cases when the internet connection is back up, I will go through a ArrayList to get all of the offline data and send it back to the server, but sometimes it just doesn't happen (I suppose it has something to do with synchronization of AsyncTask).
   So is there any safer and consistent way of sending POST data to the server?

Answer (score 1):

You can use local storage mechanism like SQLite or Realm.

For SQLite follow this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

For Realm follow this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-realm-database-replacing-sqlite-core-data/)

Hope this will help you to achieve your goal.

Happy Coding!!!